# Where does Electron save previous zoom?

Tags: electron, chromium

Electron appears to remember what the zoom factor when restarting the app - where is this saved?  I want to be able to reset this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The zoom factor information for each browser window is memorized in a JSON file named `Preferences` located in the user data directory accessible through `app.getPath ('userData');`

If the zoom factor is different from its default value `1.0`, it will be listed at the end of the JSON file (after the DevTools settings), associated with the window's URL. You may find the whole relevant syntax quite odd though...

Comment: That was it, thanks!  In my case the Preferences file was in C:\Users\<<username>>\AppData\Roaming\<<package name>>\

Answer (score 3):

As a user said, you must find `Preferences` file in `C:\Users\<<username>>\AppData\Roaming\<<package name>>`. I tried to change `zoom` value firstly but it didn't work. After I tried to change `per_host_zoom_levels` to `0` and it works.
So if you want to manipulate zoom from saved file, you must change `per_host_zoom_levels`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this, but could be in:

`C:\Users\**<name>**\AppData\Local\Temp`

and then in a folder relative of the name of the app.

Comment: For me, it turned out to be in C:\Users\<<username>>\AppData\Roaming\<<package name>>\

Answer (score 0):

The file structure should be `C:\Users\%YOUR-USER%\AppData\Roaming\%YOUR-APP%\`, edit the `Preferences` file with an editor (I used notepad), look for `{per_host_zoom_levels": {"%SOME-NUMBER%":{%HERE%}}}`. At the `%HERE%` part will have the zoom preference, delete the contents to reset and so that `{per_host_zoom_levels": {"%SOME-NUMBER%":{}}}` remains. Can augment to have different values as well. Hope it helps for future readers!